# How to change CVPixelBuffer data format

Tags: swift, coreml, cvpixelbuffer

I convert UIImage to CVPixelBuffer for the CoreML, but I want change the RGB pixel, like R/1.5, G/2, B/2.5.

I can read the pixel data by using `assumingMemoryBound(to : UInt8.self)`,but 
how can I modify the pixel data in CVPixelBuffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do this in the CVPixelBuffer? Core ML can automatically do this for you as part of the model.

When you convert your model to Core ML you can specify an `image_scale` preprocessing option.

In your case it looks like you want different scales for each color channel, which you can do by adding a scaling layer to the model. See the following Jupyter notebook for an example: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/master/examples/Image_preprocessing_per_channel_scale.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried this method, but I got nothing by using spec.neuralNetwork, do you have any thoughts?

Comment: What sort of model are you using?

Comment: I am soory that I don't know what is the sort of model means, I converted the h5 model to mlmodel by using this code:

`coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model, input_names='image', image_input_names='image', red_bias=redbias, green_bias=greenbias, blue_bias=bluebias, output_names='prediction', class_labels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

Is there any problems?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have understood the problem you said. I changed the `spec.neuralNetwork` to `spec.neuralNetworkClassifier` and solved this problem.